# How do I change all references from one type to another using Mono.Cecil?

Tags: .net, reflection, mono, mono.cecil

I need to replace all references to a particular type, and replace them with references to another type. I remember Mono.Cecil had a ReferenceVisitor class some time ago, but it seems to be gone. How can I solve my task with current version of Mono.Cecil?